# QDialog Help [?] Button does not trigger whatsthis event

Tags: c++, qt

I have created following dialog using QT designer form class

```
#ifndef DLG_GAMMA_H
#define DLG_GAMMA_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dlg_Gamma;
}

class Dlg_Gamma : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dlg_Gamma(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dlg_Gamma() override;

private slots:
    void on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value);
    void on_saveButton_clicked();
    void on_discardButton_clicked();
    void on_resetButton_clicked();

signals:
    void savechanges(QString filter);
    void discardchanges();
    void reset();

private:
    Ui::Dlg_Gamma *ui;
    bool eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event) override;
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *dlg) override;
    bool close_X;

};

#endif // DLG_GAMMA_H
```

.cpp

```
bool Dlg_Gamma::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event->type();
}
```

However, clicking on help button, does not trigger any event.

Has anybody faced this issue before ?
Does anybody know solution ?

Comment: How does this code relate to the problem .. ? Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool MyDialog::event(QEvent *e)
{
// reimplement event processing
if(e->type()==QEvent::WhatsThisClicked)
{
QWhatsThisClickedEvent ce = static_cast<QWhatsThisClickedEvent>(e);
....
return true;
}
return QDialog::event(e);
}
```

This is the event catcher.
To use event filter you need to install it: 
`installEventFilter(this)` in the constructor of the Dialog.

Comment: ? is default button. Can't use installEventFilter like ui->helpButton

Comment: oh, yes. Sorry. Just use it on the Dialog itself. Add `installEventFilter(this)` in constructor. But to be honest, you don't need the eventFilter. You just need the event catcher. These are two ways of doing this. the filter or the catcher

Comment: Yes. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install eventFilter on your 'help button' when using eventFilter.

You need to insert kind of code below in the constructor of the 'Dlg_Gamma'

```
ui->helpButton->installEventFilter(this)
```

For more information, Please refer to the information below.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html